# find a matrix such that $KX=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be an $n \times p$ matrix. I would like to find a matrix $K$ such that $KX=0$. An obvious matrix is $K=I-X(X'X)^{-1}X'$.

I'm wondering if there are other matrices that satisfy $KX=0$?

Comment: $K=0$ (of the appropriate dimension) ought to work. That's the most obvious one in my opinion.

Comment: If $K$ works then so does $cK$ for any scalar $c$.

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to exclude such trivial cases.

Comment: @user0131 Consider generalised inverse/s of $X$ (you have considered one), ie matrices $X^-$ sfor which $XX^-X=X$ .

Comment: If  $n \geq p$ then you can set  the rows of $K$ as linear combinations of $ \ker X'$.

Comment: How do you know that $X'X$ is invertible? You’ve given no conditions on $X$ other than its size.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X^-$ be a generalised inverse of $X $. Then 
\begin{equation} (I-XX^- )X=0.\end{equation}

So if $X $ is not invertible, the answer will be that there are other $K $'s.

Comment: You can find the general form of $X^-$ using the inner inverse you have already considered.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $KX=0$ is equivalent to  $\text{Im}\,X \subseteq \text{Ker}\,K$.
Let $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ be an orthonormal basis of $\text{Im}\,X$ and $u_1,\ldots, u_l$ an orthonormal basis of $(\text{Im}\,X)^\perp$, so that $(v_1,\ldots,v_k,u_1,\ldots,u_l)$ is an ONB of $\mathbb R^n$

Then any $m\times n$ matrix of the form

$$K = \sum_{i=1}^l |\alpha_i\rangle\langle u_i|   $$

where $\alpha_i\in\mathbb R^m$ suffices $KX=0$. Conversely, any matrix satisfying $KX=0$ is of the given form for some choice of the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for many suggestions!